# How to Disable Paste option for alphabets and Special Characters but Enabled for Numbers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, numbers, paste

I Used this code for restricting to type `alphabets` and `characters`.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Width="15%"   onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>
```

But I am able to `Paste` the `alphabets` and `characters` in it(Which I don't want).

When I used this code, The `Paste Option` is `disabled` but,I cant `Paste` even Numbers

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Width="15%" ondrop="return false;"
     onpaste="return false;" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

But I want to `paste` the `Numbers` :(,How can I do that ?.

Comment: You can opt for third party plugin. [Limit Text Box jQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/m-jq-projects/wikis/limitTextBox_jQuery.wiki). When plugin configuration is set to "numbers" will limit characters to only numbers only. Any pasted non-numeric characters will be filtered out and what remains will be a number.

Comment: tried but not working either ?please give me a specific code..that will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use `type="number"` to have a semantic meaning and form validation like `HtML5` in mordern browser, and to get the live functionality in all the browser you can try this:

```js
function isNumber(ev) {
    if (ev.type === "paste" || ev.type === "drop") {
        var textContent = (ev.type === "paste" ? ev.clipboardData : ev.dataTransfer).getData('text');
        return !isNaN(textContent) && textContent.indexOf(".") === -1;
    } else if (ev.type === "keydown") {
        if (ev.ctrlKey || ev.metaKey) {
            return true
        };
        var keysToAllow = [8, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57];
        return keysToAllow.indexOf(ev.keyCode) > -1;
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="paste numbers only" name="" onpaste="return isNumber(event)" onkeydown="return isNumber(event)" ondrop="return isNumber(event)">
```

Remove the second condition if `&& pasteContent.indexOf(".")===-1` if you want to allow `integer` as well as `floating point` numbers. but allowing floating point number will cause a problem if you already have a floating point number, so it will be invalid number with two `"."`

Comment: This code is working but when i implement this , i can type the aplhabets can u give a code where u can only type and paste numbers

Comment: Sure, wait, I am updating my aswer

Comment: Ya Thank you...:)

Comment: working nicely thank you:) i just removed that ondownkey because i wasn't able to use the numpad when I removed it works fine

Comment: @Kaushik it would be really good if u tell me how to stop even the drag part I am able to drag the aplhabets :(

Comment: @Frost_Mourne updated the answer again. Try understanding how the code is written and try to implement by yourself once you learned it :)

Comment: one more problem, now i can write aplhabets in it,Its ok for me but for one who is searching an answer for it on stack ,Your answer might be helpfull hope u find a solution

Comment: you meant you are able to type alphabets in it?? but its working for me. check in the snippet itself.

Comment: no no no got the error i removed on keydown because the num pad is not working I put that back now its working fine....how to solve that problem for num pad the numbers below the F1,2,3... are working,But num pad naah not working

Comment: well those are server side event you are assigning which triggers on server postback, try instead the javascript solution, or add the events through `addEventListener` and invoke `preventDefault()` on the `event`, so the js code will run to get wha you want.

Comment: `isNaN(textContent)` this thing will give u error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Comment: @NikhilPatel that is happening because you are using it in typescript, in that case try declaring textContent as any type `let textContent:any`, and then it executes well in JavaScripts with any kind of input.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution using a timeout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="inputText" onpaste="return isNumber(event);" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"  value="" size="40">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 function isNumber(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      var element  = document.getElementById("inputText");
      var initialValue  = element.value;
      if(evt.type == "paste"){
         setTimeout(function() {
           var value  = element.value;
         var pastedText = value.replace(initialValue,"");
            if(!isNaN(pastedText)){
             element.value = value;
            }else{
             element.value = initialValue;
            }
          }, 2);         
      }
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should i keep this code too?"ondrop="return false;"
     onpaste="return false;""

Comment: Tried but not working..:("                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Width="15%" onpaste="return isNumber(event)"  onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>
"

Comment: not needed. Try with `onpaste="return isNumber(event)"`

Comment: do i need JS for this? "onpaste="return isNumber(event)"

Comment: `onpaste` executes the JS that follows the `=`

Comment: Your's is working fine but, But I want it in<asp:TextBox /> not <input Type="Text" />,Thank you :)